# Matlab waitbar - close all doesn't work

Tags: matlab, figure

I have some code which creates a waitbar:

```
if long_process %user specifies this true/false
    h = waitbar(1/4, msg);
end
process(arg1,arg2);
```

Process is some function which does some plotting. If I do CTRL-C somewhere in process and I get left with a figure window I can just do close all and the figure disappears. However, the waitbar stays. I don't know how to make that thing close with 'close all'.

The reason this is bothering is because when I start debugging I often end up having 20+ waitbars open. 'close all' then comes in handy.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually, the [`close`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/close.html) function gives you some more "forceful" options:

```
close all hidden
close all force
```

And if for some reason those don't work, one "nuclear" option you have is to *delete* all figures, including those with hidden handles, as suggested in the [`close`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/close.html) and [`waitbar`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waitbar.html) documentation:

```
set(0, 'ShowHiddenHandles', 'on');
delete(get(0, 'Children'));
```

You may find it easiest to create your own helper function to do this for you (and return the state of [`'ShowHiddenHandles'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.root-properties.html#buc8_0n-ShowHiddenHandles) to its default `'off'` state) so you don't have as much to type:

```
function killEmAll
  set(0, 'ShowHiddenHandles', 'on');
  delete(get(0, 'Children'));
  set(0, 'ShowHiddenHandles', 'off');
end
```

...And even a *third* option is to try and avoid the problem altogether (if the organization of your code allows it) by using [`onCleanup` objects](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/oncleanup.html)! If you run the following sample code, the waitbar should be automatically deleted for you when you <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> out of the infinite loop:

```
function runprocess
  h = waitbar(1/4, 'la la la...');
  waitObject = onCleanup(@() delete(h));
  process();
end

function process
  i = 1;
  while (i > 0)
    i = i + 1;
  end
end
```

Comment: `onCleanup` objects is the way to go.  After all the documentation says: "All objects that are local variables in a function are implicitly cleared at the termination of that function, whether by normal completion or by a forced exit such as an error or **Ctrl+C**. When function F terminates, MATLAB clears the cleanupObj object by calling its object destructor method."